# Pass a list of files to sftp get

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sftp, file-transfer

I am looking for an 'sftp' alternative to the following command:

```
cat list_of_files_to_copy.txt | xargs -I % cp -r % -t /target/folder/
```

: Read a text file containing the folder paths to be copied, and pass each line (here using xargs) to a copy command `cp` to process them one-by-one.

I want to do this so I can parallelize the copying process, using partitions of all folders I can give each one as a different text file to multiple copying command on separate terminals (if this does not work as I am expecting to work please comment).

For some reason, the copy command is very slow in my system (even if I don't try to parallelize), whereas doing `sftp get` seems more efficient.

Any way I can implement this using `sftp get` ?

Answer (score 0):

scp is the non interactive version of sftp, why don't you just create a loop like this

```
for F in $(<list_of_files_to_copy.txt);do
    scp source destination
done
```